.band file is damaged or has incorrect file format in swift
I try to export audio as .band file, but GarageBand says file is damaged or has incorrect format
func copyAudioFileToDocuments(ringtone: Ringtone?) async throws -> URL? {
        guard let ringtone, let documentsURL = ringtone.url else { return nil }
                
        
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: documentsURL)
        let exportAudioMix = AVMutableAudioMix()
        
        guard let track = try await asset.load(.tracks).last else { return nil }

        let start = ringtone.info.startTime
        let length = ringtone.info.endTime - ringtone.info.startTime
        
        let exportTimeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .init(seconds: start, preferredTimescale: 1),
                                          duration: .init(seconds: length, preferredTimescale: 1))

        
        let destinationURL = Constants.cachesDirectory.appendingPathComponent(ringtone.id.replacingOccurrences(of: ringtone.info.title.ext.rawValue, with: "band"))
        try await exportAudio(from: track, mix: exportAudioMix, exportTimeRange: exportTimeRange, to: destinationURL)
        return destinationURL
    }

------------------->
func exportAudio(from track: AVAssetTrack, mix: AVAudioMix? = nil, exportTimeRange: CMTimeRange? = nil, to destinationURL: URL) async throws {
        let composition = AVMutableComposition()
        let compositionAudioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
        let duration = try await track.asset?.load(.duration)
        try compositionAudioTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: duration ?? .init()), of: track, at: .zero)
        
        let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)
        if let exportTimeRange { exportSession?.timeRange = exportTimeRange }
        exportSession?.outputURL = destinationURL
        exportSession?.audioMix = mix
        exportSession?.outputFileType = AVFileType.aiff
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationURL.path) {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destinationURL)
        }
        try await exportSession?.exportAsync()
    }

I tried with .mp3 extension and everything was ok, but with .band it is not working.

Are you sure that .band is not a proprietary file format and that .band files are simple audio files? I'd assume that .band files are container files that represent a GarageBand project and that this format is proprietary and cannot be created outside GarageBand. Why are you trying to create such a file outside of GarageBand? Why can't you just save your audio into a regular file format and import that into an existing GarageBand project?

Download "Tik RIngtones" app from App Store and you will see that flow

A .band file is not actually a sound file. It isn't a file at all. It is (as you have already been told in a comment) a package, i.e. a folder disguised as a file; inside the folder is an entire GarageBand project. It is up to you to know how to construct the contents of the folder correctly; AVAssetExportSession is not going to magically make one for you.

I succeed to create the project folder and export, but now there is another problem, when I export on session I set the duration, but whatever duration I set, Audio Recording#1.wav audio file has the correct duration, but in the project it is either ~5 second, or ~ 11 seconds, I think something is wrong with project metadata.
